# screen off does not Recive Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Screen Off ,Broadcast Receiver does not call some time it will execute but mostly wifi state change event is called .i have also set up the priority of screen off but does not call  or some time call .can you please tell .when my screen off i want to execute first then other wifi state changed will called

```
BroadcastReceiver wReceiver = new ScreenReciver();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    filter.setPriority(1);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.setPriority(1000);
    registerReceiver(wReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(wReceiver);
    super.onPause();

}
```

```
public class ScreenReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch (wifiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:

            Intent myintent = new Intent(context, TimerClockActivity.class);
            myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myintent);
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLED";
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(context, TimerClockActivity.class);
            myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myintent);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `unregisterReceiver(wReceiver);` in `onPause()`. This means that every time that the Activity goes into the background (including when the screen turns off), your Activity is unregistered for that broadcast.

onPause() is likely getting called before your Activity gets a chance to receive the Broadcast.

Perhaps you want to place `unregisterReceiver(wReceiver);` in `onDestroy()` instead?

Comment: can i develop the separate Broadcast Receiver class for WiFi and screen off ?